# How to change a column value in the PySpark dataframe with a datatype of an array of structs

Tags: python, dataframe, apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

How to change a column value in the PySpark dataframe with a datatype of an `array` of `structs`, for example, I would like to divide `long_value` by 10.

```
root
 |-- properties: array (nullable = true)
 |    |-- element: struct (containsNull = true)
 |    |    |-- key: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |-- value: struct (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- string_value: string (nullable = true)
 |    |    |    |-- long_value: long (nullable = true)
```

I tried to achieve it by using the `withColumn` method but the approach returns the same df.

```
df.withColumn("properties.value.long_value", col("properties")[0]["value"]["long_value"] / 10 )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using [`transform`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.functions.transform.html#pyspark.sql.functions.transform) function along with column method [`withField`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/reference/pyspark.sql/api/pyspark.sql.Column.withField.html):

```py
df1 = df.withColumn(
    "properties",
    F.transform(
        "properties",
        lambda x: x.withField("value", x["value"].withField("long_value", x["value"].getField("long_value") / 10))
    )
)
```